# GWT Widget ID and HTML standard

Tags: gwt, web

I have a custom widget (`OrderItem`) in a GWT project. This widget has a `TextBox`. I set  it's id to "Navid". But what if I create multiple instances of `OrderItem` in a panel? The id would be repeated then. This'd make the html invalid.

How do I assign a unique id to the TextBox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, normally, GWT widgets generate their own IDs that will automatically be unique and you would not typically worry about what the ID is.  When you say that you are setting the ID of a TextBox, I'm assuming that you're calling something like `myTextBox.getElement().setId("Navid")`.

There are two simple methods I can think of, depending on your use-case.  The HTMLPanel class has a static createUniqueId() method on it that you can use either on its own, or to easily create a unique id.  Like `myTextBox.getElemement().setId("Navid-" + HTMLPanel.createUniqueId())`.  The only problem with this is that the ID that is generated is not deterministic.

The other common method would be to generate an ID based on the ID of the parent widget. `myTextBox.getElement().setId("Navid-" + myTextBox.getParent().getElement().getId())`.

However, I'm going to take a guess here and assume that the reason why you're wanting to assign your own custom ID to this widget is so that you can address it from outside of your GWT code, from Javascript, for example, from JQuery.  In this case, I would recommend that instead of assigning an ID to it, which has to be unique to be useful, that you instead assign an html class name to the widget's element.  You would then address the widget's element relative to the id, or class of your OrderItem's id or class.  You can add an html class name to an element as in the example `myTextBox.getElement().addStyleName("navid")`

So, assuming that you assign an html class of orderItemWidget to the root HTML element of your OrderItem widget, and an html class of navid to the TextBox, you could refer to the textbox from a JQuery with the selector `".orderItemWidget .navid"`

Answer (score 2):

This is why GWT makes it doesn't make it that easy to set an ID on a widget. For styling, it makes it much easier to use CSS class names. Actually, there are very few reasons to use an ID to begin with, and almost none for dynamically generated things (like widgets).

Now, to answer your question, browsers tolerate the case of several elements sharing the same ID, and `getElementById` [is defined](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#dom-document-getelementbyid) to return the first of those elements (in document order)